# Tweedie distribution error in R

Tags: r, distribution, tweedie

I cannot debug the following Tweedie error in R. The tweedie function code has worked in other applications and I have checked the data. Any help would be appreciated.

```
glm1a <- glm(Incurred_Loss   ~  operator_age_group + credit_group + 
             motor_length_group +stated_amount_group + Marine_Age_group,
             family=tweedie(var.power=tweedie.p, link.power=0),
             data=Tnwater1.df, offset=log(Exposure),
             weights=Exposure^(tweedie.p - 1))
```

Error in if (!(validmu(mu) && valideta(eta))) stop("cannot find valid starting values: please specify some",  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In log(mu) : NaNs produced

Comment: Without a reproducible example is difficult to help you. Please provide an example that we can run and which produces the same error.

Comment: you can also try the `cplm` package